# Parse YAML List in Golang

Tags: go, parsing, yaml

I'm trying to parse such a YAML:

```yaml
a:
  - opt:
    f1: "lol"
  - opt:
    f1: "lul"
```

Using such structures:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
a:
  - opt:
    f1: "lol"
  - opt:
    f1: "lul"
`

type T struct {
    As []A `yaml:"a"`
}

type A struct {
    Opts []Opt `yaml:"opt"`
}

type Opt struct {
    F1 string `yaml:"f1"`
}

func main() {
    t := T{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)
}
```

But it gives me only empty lists:

```
--- t:
{[{[]} {[]}]}
```

What's wrong with this code? [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_fsFBsJ4Kg2)

Comment: Is `f1` supposed to be in the same object as `opt`? or is it supposed to be nested in `opt`?

Comment: @mkopriva, it's supposed to be nested

Comment: Then the yaml document should reflect that, currently `f1` is at the same level as `opt`. Also opt seems to be a single object in the yaml file rather than a sequence, so drop the `[]` from it. https://go.dev/play/p/VpcxvAhr0z0

Comment: An alternative that's still nested but that doesn't require the yaml document to reflect the nesting, would be to use embedding in Go and `,inline` in the yaml tag: https://go.dev/play/p/ZanNToY_tjt